# How do Germans call someone from the United States?

Tags: single-word-request, english-to-german

If *the United States* is translated to *Vereinigte Staaten* then how do you call people from there?

I have always heard *Amerikaner* but that one refers to the whole continent.

Comment: [Related question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20669/rationale-for-the-compound-adjective-us-amerikanisch)

Comment: And if not? Suspicious dependency injection. ;)

Comment: Calling someone _Amerikaner_ and basing that on the continent (not country) of origin, is about as useful and common as the term _Eurasier_ or _Eurasiate_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Amerikaner

*Amerikaner*, like its English equivalent, is a bit ambiguous but very common, even in official contexts, and rarely refers to all inhabitants of or people originating from the Americas.  It could even be used informally in some contexts to refer to a German person with American citizenship.  It also has some other meanings in reference to physical things, like a pastry.  One could also say *einen Amerikaner fahren* to mean *to drive an American car*.

#### Ami

*Ami* is derived from *Amerikaner*, but it specifically refers to people from the United States, including US soldiers in Germany.  Also, more so than *Amerikaner*, it can be used in compounds (eg *ein echter Ami-Wagen*), but by itself it almost always refers to people — one does not hear *einen Ami fahren* referring to a car.  It is not pejorative per se, but it does tend to connote the full-strength American stereotype in culture and politics.  Angela Merkel would probably avoid it, but a drunken uncle will happily speak of the *Amis* when providing Stammtisch political analysis on the actions of the government in Washington DC.  As the least formal, it is definitely the top choice for *Du Scheiß____!*  It also has the feature of being less comprehensible than *Amerikaner* to the average English speaker — sometimes that’s a plus.

#### US-Amerikaner

This is very precise, and much more common in formal German than the equivalent *US-American* is in English.  There is also a useful corresponding adjective, *US-amerikanisch*.  (However *US-Amerika* is rare.)  It would be atypical to say “Bist Du US-Amerikaner?”, unless the emphasis were required in context.

Proposals like *Staatler* or *Vereinigtenstaatler* — which is also not precise, as there are other *United States of X* in the world — never found much traction, proportionally much less than, say, *Emirater*.

#### US-Bürger | amerikanischer Staatsbürger

This simply means *U.S. citizen* or *American citizen*, and is as such is technical and corresponds nearly exactly with the English translation.

Some other notes:

In German one does not use *US* for the United States (it is *USA*). However the prefixing compound is indeed *US-*.  *VS* (from *Vereinigten Staaten*) is exceedingly rare.

The rules for the country name are another topic.  For example *die Staaten* is very common, and there are fixed expressions like *der Onkel aus Amerika*.

There are similar issues regarding the words for people from or citizens of the United Kingdom.

Comment: How are people from the UAE called then?

Comment: I tend to say *Emirater*, but I believe *Emirati* (pl *Emiratis*) is the formal version.  Of course, as in English, it is also ambiguous because there are other emirates in the world (same for *das Banat* and *Banater*), and because it is frequently used to denote the original Emiratis not the recently naturalised.  Then there are *Staatsbürger der VAE* and *Einwohner der VAE* (although the English abbreviation *UAE* is widely understood), or *der Emiraten* (less formal).

Answer (score 18):

#### [Amerikaner](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Amerikaner)

In Germany it is exactly the same as in the United States:

> We are Americans <sup>[Obama's weekly address Jan 15 2011](http://www.whitehouse.gov/blog/2011/01/15/weekly-address-we-are-democrats-or-republicans-we-are-americans)</sup>

literally translates to

> *Wir sind Amerikaner*
> <sup>(this obviously is not true then)</sup>

Only if we need to further specify where a person lives we could also say:

> *Nordamerikaner* - North American
> *Südamerikaner* - South American
> *Texaner* - Texan
> *Südstaatler* - Southerner
> *Kanadier* - Canadian
> *Mexikaner* - Mexican
> [...] <sup>endless list</sup>

---

#### [Ami](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ami_Amerikaner_Einwohner)

A short form frequently used in colloquial German is

> *Ami*

that has the connotation of a *friend* from French *"ami"*.

---

#### [US-Bürger](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/US_Buerger)

Note that in Germany we do not use *"U.S."* for the United States (it is *"USA"*). Still we do say

> *"US-Bürger"* for a U.S. citizen

Comment: +1 for _Ami_. In colloquial use, one often hears _die Amis_ - but for me it doesn't have the connotation your describing.

Comment: _Ami_ has a neutral connotation, leaning slightly to the negative, since it is often used in generalizations `Die Amis lieben Fast Food`. To my knowledge it doesn't have anything to do with the French "ami".

Comment: In the former Federal Republic of Germany Ami was used in context with the occupying forces and the connotation was mostly neutral, but partly ambiguous. Today there is a tendency not use Ami to denote individual persons, but to use it when  expressing prejudices.

Comment: The *friend* connotation for Ami is new to me. On the other hand, the word does not have a slightly negative connotation for me, it's fine.

Comment: We also sometimes use "GI" as term for american soldiers, at least my mother does. I don't know if we differentiate between army, navy and air force when using this abbreviation.
Ami is also a short form of a first name .. was it Michael?

Comment: @HendrikVogt +1 "Ami" is NOT related to the french "ami". It is almost always used in a negative context. It seems to be some kind of equivalent term for when german people are called "Krauts"!

Comment: @bodycountPP: the "always negative" context you mentioned is not what I experience. This is confirmed by what other people said above. The connotation (which is **not** of any etymological relationship)  to the French *ami* may have somewhat been lost over time and in certain social groups but it was present in the 50ies and early 60ies when the term arose.

Comment: Please note that not only have the German and French "ami" nothing in common linguistically, they are pronounced in a different way: the Germans place the accent on the "a" (it's almost like aaami) while the French on the "i".

Comment: @vsz the "A" in "Ami" is short, though

Comment: @Lykanion : but longer than in the French "ami", because the French put the weight in the "i" at the end.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on the context. Normally an *Amerikaner* will be identified as someone from US.

If you have a situation where you want to make it absolutly clear, you can say *US-Amerikaner*.

---

In a bakery, an [*Amerikaner*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerikaner_%28Geb%C3%A4ck%29) can be eaten ;)

Comment: US(A)-Bürger and (most important ;p) Ami

Answer (score 6):

In Germany we use *Amerika* as a synonym to the country *U.S.A,* allthough using it at the same time for referring to the continent, but usually adding *Nord-* or *Süd-*.

Thus, the inhabitants of the country are called *Amerikaner*. When talking about people from other countries on the continent, we are either using their country’s name, like *Kanadier* or *Mexikaner*, or adding a region information, like *Südamerikaner* or *Lateinamerikaner*.

Comment: "allthough using it at the same time for referring to the continent, but usually adding Nord- or Süd-." - well, that depends. I think it is also not unusual to use just "Amerika" to refer to the continent(s), but it should be noted here that the plural "die Amerikas" is *not* used in German. This is in contrast to English, where North America + South America = the Americas is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we would say US-Bürger (US-citizen) or US-Amerikaner (US-American), as said above.

But often we would just use Ami or Amis (Plural).

Just to clarify, even though it is spelled like the French *ami* there is no connection. "Ami" is informal and has, contrary to what was says above, no positive connotations. Few would honestly say "Sche%ß US-Bürger" (fu%king US- Citizen) , most likely they would say "Sche%ß Ami" (Fu%king Ami). "Ami" could be called the less offensive German version of the American offensive slang for Japanese --> "Jap".

Comment: Sorry, but with people I talk to a negative usage of *Ami* is definitely not what I see. Of course there is no etymological connection to the French *ami* but the connotation (which is something entirely different) used to be there at the times the term arose in the German language.

Comment: While terms such as *Japse* or *Itaker* definitely carry a derogative connotation in the word itself, this is not the case for *Ami.* To make it derogatory, it *needs* a derogative modifier. *Scheißami* works just like *Scheißjapse* does, however the latter carries a double insult while to former *does not.*

Comment: Kommt sehr auf den Kontext an. Wenn eine einzelne, bekannte Person (zum Beispiel ein neuer Kollege) Ami genannt wird, dann ist das wahrscheinlich beleidigend gemeint. Für allgemeine Amerikaner ist das weniger so.